# Create new tag in rmarkdown

Tags: html, css, r-markdown

I need to change font style within a Rmarkdown document's HTML output. Specifically, I want to create numbered figure and table captions that contrast from the rest of the text by size.

Currently I'm using inline css.

```
<style type="text/css">

div.caption {
    font-size:0.85em;
}

div.captionheader {
    font-size:0.85em;
    font-weight: bold;
}
</style>
```

Then I use the styles in the text written, incrementing `figure_counter` each time.

```
<div class="captionheader">Figure `r figure_counter`:</div>
<div class="caption"> This is the caption text.</div>
```

The chunk option `fig.cap` doesn't cut it as a counter variable is not available and doesn't print the `figure_counter` variable. Although I'm open for corrections.

Is there a more elegant way of defining the styles in the text?

I imagine to define a similar token like `#` defines h1.

Would it be possible to define e.g. `%caption_header%` and `%%caption_text%%` ?

Comment: Have you tried to `result='asis'`  in the chunk options? You could use a code chunk to evaluate your `figure_counter` variable and print the html text you want.

Comment: @drmariod I tried it in different contexts, but this is not what i want. I want - in the ideal world - type less. A complete chunk would mess up even more. Printing `figure_counter` via \`r figure_counter\` is already quite nice for inline r chunks.